# Trouble installing packages from packrat log file

Tags: r, docker, package-management, renv, packrat

I am trying to work with some code that was written with R/3.6* and its packages. See the lock file at https://gist.github.com/khanna7/cb5791bdf65df55d320fd098d6093b1b. The main package I need, from the lock file, is

```
Package: ergm
Source: CRAN
Version: 3.10.4
Hash: 40111d398c8f561201b554bc4eb99d73
Requires: coda, dplyr, lpSolve, network, purrr, rlang, robustbase,
    statnet.common, tibble, trust
```

I can load R/3.6.3 or 3.6.1. If I try to install this ergm version, I get the error at https://gist.github.com/khanna7/eaa980b3ba5d508c1f3bb03fb6a2829c .

I also have a docker image, but this doesn't seem to load the main libraries that I need.

Any ideas would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My system R profile `~/.Rprofile` was sourcing the `renv` file. I commented out that line, and I was able to install the packages in the log file via `packrat::restore()`.